# There's a discrepancy between the number of starred messages reported at different places

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars

In the C++ [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec), the number of all starred messages is currently reported in the right-hand panel as ***3407***.
That number is a link, and if I click on it, it takes me to [an info page with a tab saying ***5.9k*** stars.

[image: 3407]
[image: 5.9k]

I'm sure there is an explanation for this discrepancy, but I'd like to think it is a bug no matter what the explanation is.

Comment: +1 I can attest to this.

Comment: We all know this is a shameless advertisement of the C++ chat room disguised as a bug report.

Comment: @hexa: For one, the C++ room doesn't need any advertising, it's been hard to breath in there for days. (And no wonder, [C++ is currently undergoing a renaissance](http://carmine.blogs.com/kernel/2011/02/c-renaissance.html)!) But also, even if it were, it would have been pretty stupid of you to blurt this out while we all kept our mouths firmly shut about it.

Comment: Don't you remember the 1st and 2nd rule of the C++ room?

Answer (score 6):

There are 3407 messages, which are cumulatively starred 5.9k times. It might make more sense if the stars tab was actually the *starred* tab so that the number would be consistent, since I imagine most people are interested in the number of messages starred (although the number of total stars could still be shown somewhere on that page).

Comment: Ah, this might be the explanation I knew someone would come up with. It might be totally true, but it's totally confusing still.

Comment: I agree, this definitely isn't the first time there's been some confusion over the difference.

Comment: The same thing happens with flags on the actual sites; some places show the number of flagged posts and some show the total number of flags